# uicontrol clipping in 2016b

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have a figure with a Panel on it. This Panel has some uicontrols on it that are its own Children (let's say a checkbox, a popupmenu, an edit).

These uicontrols are placed on the Panel in such a way that they (should) display partly outside of it (yet still inside the figure).

In HG1 (R2014a and before), this works fine and "as expected" : uicontrols are displayed normally and the part that is "drawn" outside the parent Panel is drawn normally : [image: Old, nice behaviour]

Now I have R2016b with the new HG2 graphics system. The same figure doesn't display correctly anymore. The uicontrols are displayed "cropped" : the part that should appear outside the parent Panel is cropped/clipped and just doesn't appear at all : [image: new, bad behaviour]

The figure and the panel both have their "Clipping" property set to off, yet this seems to have no impact.

How can I get these uicontrols to display in HG2 (R2014b+) as they did in HG1 (R2014a and before) ?

Comment: One picture of the figure could save you many words, and make the question much more clear.

Comment: Says [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uipanel-properties.html#property_d0e1049842): "The behavior of the Clipping property has changed. It no longer has any effect on uipanels. Child objects are now clipped to the uipanel boundary regardless of the value of this property." You may just have to make your panels bigger to hold everything.

Comment: @gnovice : ok, any idea how to bypass this ? Enlarging the Panel is awful as i do want the uicontrols getting out of it. The other solution would be to change the uicontrols parent and make it the figure, but for other reasons that complexifies things for me.